# Lookup of function RFC_READ_TABLE metadata failed for destination PP1

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm using a C# program to retrieve table's data from SAP, the .dll files I used is from SAP .NET CONNECTOR, I got an issue when calling below statements:

`RfcDestination destination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(cmbAsset.Text);
readTable = destination.Repository.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");`

Error message is:
“SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException”: Unhandled Exception occurred in sapnco.dll

Other information: Lookup of function RFC_READ_TABLE metadata failed for destination PP1

The thing is, I have several items in combobox 'cmbAsset', for some items above statements executed normally but for others they didn't. Besides, I've set the attibutes of sapnco.dll and sapnco_utils.dll as 'copy to local=true', is there anything wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried other RFC-functions? Are you getting the same issues? Maybe some access-rights are missing? Can you access transaction SE16? You could also try using the Business Blue Print (BBP)-ReadTable. It has some advantages and is newer.

Comment: Thank for replying, I contacted tech team, and they gave me another account, I guess this was caused by user's access-rights.